# Deleting with a FK using RESTful API design

Tags: rest

I have a table called `itemlink` which contains three columns `id`,`parentId`,`childId`

According to [this article](https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9) if I want to get all itemlinks then I'd call `GET /itemlink` and if I want to get all itemlinks that belong to a particular parent then I'd add in a query string `GET /itemlink?parentId=5` and that parameter is optional

But what if I'm dealing with delete and I want to give the client the ability to delete all itemlinks that belong to a particular parent, I don't feel comfortable having a url that would delete all itemlinks `DEL /itemlink`, that doesn't sound like best (or safe) practice so what is the best way to implement this?

One of the options I can think of to force the client to add in the parentId when asking to delete is to have a end point like `/itemlink/parent/{id}` but does that break the rules of a proper REST design?

Comment: URI or API design is not one of REST's topic actually as responses should contain only links that clients can use in order to perform the task. The important thing here is not the URI itself but the relation name to teach the client what the URI is actually good for. How you build such an URI is up to you also how you trigger a delete and if it is automatically cascading. I therefore voted to close this as this question is likely to get only opinionated answers anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resources** & **Sub-resources** are involved in your case. i.e A parent-children relationship. IMO, the relationship (itemlink) should not be exposed as a resource in REST APIs, which is actually the confusing point in your case.

I will explain this with a sample usecase similar to yours.

```
Customers - Parent table 
Orders - Child table
LinkId - CustomerId - OrderId - Link table
```

In this case, the apis have to be like

```
/customers/$customer_id/orders - (GET) - Get all orders of the customer
/customers/$customer_id/orders/$order_id - (GET) - Get a particular order of the customer
/customers/$customer_id/orders - (POST) - Create a new order for the customer
/customers/$customer_id/orders/$order_id - (PUT) - Edit a particular order of the customer
/customers/$customer_id/orders/$order_id - (DELETE) - Delete all the orders of the customer
```

And coming to deleting the FK relationship, when a customer closes his account, all the orders should be dropped, which will happen through `/customers/$customer_id - HTTP DELETE`

Comment: HTTP (nor REST) define that a sub-structured URL automatically follows a parent-child relationship. To be more precise: they are not related at all by default. The relation between these two needs to be "modeled" via links. Also, deleting a "parent" resource does not automatically deduce that also the sub-resource is removed as a consequence. The HTTP spec states that no guarantee can be given that any data at all is removed. The behavior is rather implementation specific and may only remove the link between these two resources or one or both (multiple) resources.

Comment: That means itemlink is a valid resource?? Child resource should not be considered as a individual resource right?

Comment: `itemlink` is probably a table to solve N:M relationships in 3NF table setups. It is in general a bad idea to map a relational model directly onto resources as you can aggregate plenty more data into resources and link to yet other resources. There is also no right or wrong on what to use as a resource and what not. This is rather domain and problem dependent and may very also by different implementors.

Comment: There is further no right or wrong whether a sub-resource can or should be modeled as own top-level resource or not. You might apply a `can-exist-without-other-resource` schema for your URI structure. At the end REST doesn't really care as clients receive any URIs it may use from the current state with the next response received anyways and clients should further not interpret URIs but use the link relation name to determine the use of invoking the URI for. These semantics of the link relation names might be further defined in the media type or a further protocol (i.e. `next`, `prev`, ...)

Comment: IMO, if the parent resource has to be specified in order to identify the sub resource, it’s better to make it in the url instead of making it as a query parameter. But instead of the url structure in my example the customer ids, can be query parameter which can act like a filter for the orders resource as the main resource. But in case of considering an example of a member resource of an organization it is better to go with /organizations/id/members. I also strongly agree to your point that the pattern is purely developer and problem dependent.

Comment: What about when you want to delete a link, should we do a delete using all 3 ids? Even if the link id would suffice?